# Kubuntu 19.10: GUI doesn't start, but I can fix it by running startx in the system console

Tags: kubuntu, kde, xserver

My Kubuntu installation broke. To the best of my knowledge, I did nothing other than running `apt upgrade` and rebooting prior to this. All I get is a live mouse cursor after reboot, but I can switch to console (Ctrl + Alt + F2), login there, run `startx`, and then GUI loads completely as expected.

How to fix this properly? And what could have caused it?

Comment: In case you don't get a solution here, try asking at [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/forumdisplay.php/242-KDE-neon) or [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/). You could include information such as the output of `inxi -Fxxz`. (`inxi` is in the repos.)

Comment: You could also mention whether you get any errors or messages or warnings with `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt full-upgrade`.